# How can I use waka-box

Tags: github, wakatime

I want to use [waka-box](https://github.com/matchai/waka-box) at github.

I have already set secret tokens but I don`t know how to get gist id.

I read README.md but I could not understand that.

How can I get gist id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have create a public gist, you can simply find gist id from the url. It has explained in the README as well. The part in bold is the gist id.

https://gist.github.com/matchai/ **6d5f84419863089a167387da62dd7081**

Comment: There is no bold text in your answer.